# Plum Glory tree seems to be dying

Tags: fruit-trees, watering, leaves, plums

We bought a plum glory tree recently but it doesn't seem to be doing very well.

It seemed perfectly happy when we bought it and it's started growing a few plums (They are still green). However since we moved it into a larger pot some of the leaves have turned yellow and in the last couple of days they've all started to curl up. 
The most common problem on Google I've found is Aphids but there's no stickiness on the leaves.
At the moment I suspect I've not watered it enough but I wondered if anyone here has some good advice.

It's only a young tree about a meter high.

Comment: Presumably transplant shock; probably better to wait until it's dormant before repotting the next time (or the next tree, if this one does not make it.)

Comment: Hi! Would you please post some pictures? The whole tree, and close-ups of both sides of the affected leaves would be a great start. Also, where do you live? When you transplanted it, did you change the type of soil or put it into a different spot in your yard? What's your watering schedule? If you'd add those and any other details you can think of into the question, that would be great. Thanks!